# CommandButton to Increase/Decrease Probability ln Visualforce

Tags: apex, visualforce, commandbutton, custom-controller

I have a Visualforce page that has a list of opportunities with their probabilities.  I want to use commandbuttons to allow the user to increase or decrease the probability by 10% right in the list view.  I can't figure out how to get the record to update.  Below is my code:

**Visualforce Page:**

```
<apex:page controller="opportunityList2Con">
<apex:stylesheet value="{!URLFOR($Resource.ProgressStyles)}"/>
<apex:form >
<apex:pageBlock >
<apex:pageBlockTable value="{!opportunities}" var="o">
<apex:column value="{!o.Name}"/>
<apex:column value="{!o.Account.Name}"/>
<apex:column value="{!o.Type}"/>
<apex:column headerValue="Close Date">
<apex:outputField value="{!o.closeDate}"/>
</apex:column>
<apex:column headerValue="Stage">
    <div class="progress">
      <div class="progress-bar-{!o.Probability}">{!o.Probability}%</div> 
  </div>
 </apex:column>
<apex:column >
<apex:commandButton id="decrease" value="<" action="{!doSomething}" >
<apex:param name="cid" value="{!o.id}" assignTo="{!oppid}"/>
</apex:commandButton>
<apex:commandButton value=">" />
<apex:commandButton value="Won" />
<apex:commandButton value="Lost" />
</apex:column>
</apex:pageBlockTable>
</apex:pageBlock>

</apex:form>

</apex:page>
```

**Controller Code:**

```
public class opportunityList2Con {

// ApexPages.StandardSetController must be instantiated
// for standard list controllers
public ApexPages.StandardSetController setCon {
get {
if(setCon == null) {
setCon = new ApexPages.StandardSetController(Database.getQueryLocator(
[SELECT Id, Name, CloseDate, Probability, Type, Account.Name FROM Opportunity]));
}
return setCon;
}
set;
}
// Initialize setCon and return a list of records
public List<Opportunity> getOpportunities() {
return (List<Opportunity>) setCon.getRecords();
}

public PageReference save() {
    return null;
}

 public Id cid {
    get{
        if(ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('cid')!=null){
            cid = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('cid');
        }
        return cid;
    }
    set{
        if(value!=null)cid=value;
 }
}
  Opportunity selectedopportunity;
    public opportunity getselectedopportunity() {

            if(cid!=null)
            {
                selectedopportunity = [select Probability from Opportunity WHERE Id =:cid limit 1];
            }
            return selectedopportunity;
    }


// public string oppid;
    public PageReference doSomething() {
    update selectedopportunity;
    return null;
 }

}
```

Any help would be very much appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: Don't do this. Using Visualforce this way will be incredibly slow. Just add some nice JavaScript instead.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your code lines in page & class with following:

```
/******IN VF PAGE*******/
<apex:pageBlock id="mypageblockid">

<apex:commandButton id="decrease" value="<" action="{!doSomething}" reRender="mypageblockid">

/******CONTROLLER******/

if(cid!=null)
{
    selectedopportunity = [select id,Probability from Opportunity WHERE Id =:cid limit 1];
    selectedopportunity.Probability = selectedopportunity.Probability - 10;
}


public void doSomething() {
    update selectedopportunity;
    //return null;
 }
```

Hope this may help.